# Setting up maven project structure with several components

Tags: eclipse, module, maven, hudson

a question: I have three maven projects that should make up one war file. The three projects are:

simple-domain
simple-weather
simple-webapp

where simple is the parent pom. I've tried a multi module project under eclipse but I had to add relative paths to the parent project. Can someone provide me a simple set of poms or examples that would help me achieve the following:

build all projects by running maven install on the parent, run each of the three sub projects by themselve ( so it should find the parent ) and avoid using relative paths.

the latter is important as I will deploy the projects to a hudson server where each project is a job where the relative paths might differ

kind regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

You should use the standard Maven directory structure
simple
  simple-domain
  simple-weather
  simple-webapp

Then remove any relative path and use m2eclipse to handle everything in Eclipse.

Also, set up one job for simple, not one for every module. Hudson handles multiple modules well.